# Normalization of an LTI system

Tags: control-theory, linear-control

**I read a document where the author talked about normalization of an LTI system. Following was discussed:**

Let's assume an LTI system with frequency response

$$
\underline{\boldsymbol{G}}(j\omega) = \text{Re}\{\underline{\boldsymbol{G}}(j\omega)\} + j \, \text{Im}\{ \underline{\boldsymbol{G}}(j\omega) \}
$$

For a sinusoidal signal with single frequency, i.e.

$$
x(t) = x_{cos} \, \cos(\omega t) + x_{sin} \sin(\omega t) =
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{cos} & x_{sin}
\end{bmatrix}
}_{\boldsymbol{x}^\top}
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\omega t) & \sin(\omega t)
\end{bmatrix}^\top
$$

the response

$$
y(t) = y_{cos} \, \cos(\omega t) + y_{sin} \sin(\omega t) =
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
y_{cos} & y_{sin}
\end{bmatrix}
}_{\boldsymbol{y}^\top}
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\omega t) & \sin(\omega t)
\end{bmatrix}^\top
$$

can be computed (in terms of coefficients) as

$$
\boldsymbol{y} = \boldsymbol{G}(j \omega) \, \boldsymbol{x}
$$

were $\boldsymbol{G}(j \omega)$ is the real-valued version of $\underline{\boldsymbol{G}}(j \omega)$, written in matrix notation:

$$
\boldsymbol{G}(j \omega) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\text{Re}\{\boldsymbol{G}(j\omega)\} & \text{Im}\{ \boldsymbol{G}(j\omega)\} \\
-\text{Im}\{ \boldsymbol{G}(j\omega)\} & \text{Re}\{\boldsymbol{G}(j\omega)\}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now, this system $\boldsymbol{G}$ is normalized by dividing by the euclidean norm, which is:

$$
||\boldsymbol{G}(j\omega)||_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{ \text{Re}\{\boldsymbol{G}(j\omega)\}^2 + \text{Im}\{\boldsymbol{G}(j\omega)\}^2} }
$$

Therewith, the normalized system is:

$$
\boldsymbol{G}_{\text{norm}}(j\omega) =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\text{Re}\{\boldsymbol{G}(j\omega)\}^2 + \text{Im}\{\boldsymbol{G}(j\omega)\}^2}} \, \boldsymbol{G}(j\omega)
$$

**Now, my question is:**

- Is it possible to make some general statements about the normalized system with transfer function $\boldsymbol{G}_{\text{norm}}(s)$?
- In which cases is this normalization useful? (Sure, I know where the author of this document used it, but I could imagine that there are further use cases).

**Update:**

E.g. if $\boldsymbol{G}(j\omega)$ would be the identity matrix

$$
\boldsymbol{G}(j\omega) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

then this would result in following normalized matrix:

$$
\boldsymbol{G}_{\text{norm}}(j\omega) = 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Still, I can't see the usefulness here.

Comment: Shouldn't there also be a square root, assuming you want the magnitude to be normalized to one at every frequency?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen You are right, thanks. I corrected this.

Comment: After the normalization the matrix becomes orthogonal. This means it cannot change the "magnitude" (norm) of the input signal. So, you can only focus on direction changes of the input vector, which manifest itself as the phase change.